# change recipient / attach a file to a sent email in outlook

Tags: email, outlook

I've been trying to test something out, basically looking to do one of the following things:

1. Change name of recipient in a sent file. I've tried using Outlook Spy (great tool) but every time I changed the recipient in *PR_DISPLAY_TO_W* it returned the following error:

   > Could not edit the property: HrSetOneProp returned MAPL_E_COMPUTED
2. Attaching a file to a sent email file. (I don't know if this one is possible, but would be useful if it was.)

I appreciate any responses.

Answer (score 0):

1. PR_DISPLAY_TO / CC / BCC are computed properties. The store provider updates them whenever recipients list is modified.

Use the MailItem.Recipients collection to modify the recipients.

2. MailItem.Attachments.Add.